# How to consider a string with % as raw string and not as variable in Finalbuilder find and replace action.?

Tags: replace, find, finalbuilder7

I need to find and replace a particular string say {% java %} in all the html files and replace it with java. But in the file iterator while i use the find and replace method , it throws error as

*Expanding log title failed : Variable : java - does not exist!*

but in my case {% java %} is not a variable but actual string itself.

I tried "whole words only" option, which was previously selected as "Match as regular expression" under the Find tab of the action.